# Create a list with six sublists of random numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm totally new with Python; however, I would like to make a list of 6 sub-lists, each of which contains 4 random values between `0` and `30`.

The answer should print like this:

```
   lst[0] = [1,4,4,5]
   lst[1] = [23,14,5,8]
   ...
   lst[5] = [8,9,18,27]
```

Comment: Don't name your own variable `list` - it shadows the built-in. What have you tried so far, and what happened? Have you looked into the [`random` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/random.html)?

Comment: I do understand how to use the random, however i just can't figure out to create the list inside a list, by the way thank you very much for the answer :)

Comment: You can append a list to a list as you can anything else: `lst.append([1, 2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple one-liner that'll get it done:

```
from random import randint

rand_list = [[randint(0, 30) for i in range(4)] for n in range(6)]
>>>rand_list
[[28, 17, 5, 9],
[27, 29, 3, 8],
[18, 13, 4, 11],
[15, 12, 11, 19],
[17, 8, 22, 30],
[24, 6, 9, 1]]
```

If you want to get fancy, you can easily expand it into a function that will allow you to specify the list-sizes as inputs to the function:

```
def rand_lists(num_lists, num_vals):
    return [[randint(0, 30) for i in range(num_vals)] for n in range(num_lists)]


>>> rand_lists(2, 7)
[[17, 8, 29, 2, 9, 26, 16],
 [24, 22, 5, 10, 11, 0, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For a one-liner:

```
from random import randint
lst = [[randint(0, 30) for col in range(4)] for row in range(6)]
```

Which is equivalent to(in pure python):

```
lst = []
for row in range(6):
    r = []
    lst.append(r)
    for col in range(4):
        r.append(randint(0, 30))
```